# Digital Input using a button doesn't work properly when using it to control a relay

Tags: bluetooth, relay, switch, arduino-pro-micro

I'm trying to control a relay both via Bluetooth and using a switch. The problem is that, when the LED is off, I can turn it on with the switch but then if I turn off the switch the relay will stay on. Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks in advance. The switch is installed as follows: 
[image: Switch]

Here is my code: Switch is connected to pin 3 and the relay is connected to pin 2.

```cpp
//bluetooth hc-06
int ledPin = 2; // usamos un pin de salida al LED
int state = 0; // Variable lectrura serial
int interruptor=3;

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);   //Declara pin de Salida
    pinMode(interruptor, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //Normalmente Apagado
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    }

void loop() {
  int valor=digitalRead(interruptor);

  if(Serial1.available() > 0){
       state = Serial1.read();
  } // esta parte del código es para solo 1 Carácter o Unidad. 


 if (state == '0'&& valor== LOW) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial1.println("LED: off");
 }


 else
 if (state == '1' || valor== HIGH) {
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
     Serial1.println("LED: on");
 }


}
```

New code:

```cpp
//bluetooth hc-06
int ledPin = 2; // usamos un pin de salida al LED
int state = 1; // Variable lectrura serial
int interruptor=3;

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);   //Declara pin de Salida
    pinMode(interruptor, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); //Normalmente Apagado
    Serial1.begin(9600);
    }

void loop() {
  int valor=digitalRead(interruptor);
 //si el modulo ha mandado dato, guardarlo en estado.

  if(Serial1.available() > 0){
       state = Serial1.read();
  } // esta parte del código es para solo 1 Carácter o Unidad. 

 // si el estado es 0 ese sería Apagado “OFF”
 if (valor== LOW) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial1.println("LED: off");
 }

 // de lo contrario si el estado es 1 ese sería Encendido “ON”
 else
 if (valor== HIGH) {
     if (state== 1){  
     digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
     Serial1.println("LED: on");
     }
     else if (state== 0){
     digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
     Serial1.println("LED: off");

     }
 }


}
```

Comment: The circuit is working properly when using bluetooth commands, in case that helps.

Comment: Should the switch work independently from the bluetooth command on the relay? Currently you can only turn it on with state='1' AND switch on, and you can only turn it off with state='0' AND switch off. It is not completely clear, what the desired behavior is. Please explain further, what the code should do.

Comment: @chrisl: No you can turn it on with state='1' OR switch is closed. That's why he can switch the LED on with the switch but not off.

Comment: Okay, I modified my code so I can only control via bluetooth when the switch is ON, however it is still not working...

Comment: You might be better off with `boolean state = true`, then using `state = (bool)Serial1.read()` and `'if (state)...' There's nothing shown here that guarantees `Serial1.read()` will return a value of 1

Comment: The question lack critical information. What kind of data do you send over serial? Text or binary? First version of code works with characters `'0'` and `'1'`. Second version suddenly uses integer values `0` and `1`. What gives? You have to make up your mind about what you want to send. Currently the question simply makes no sense.

Comment: "I'm trying to control a relay both via Bluetooth and using a switch."   You should explain this further.  How do you want it to act?  Does one override the other?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple of problems.

In the original SW, you are checking for `state = '0'` and `state = '1'`, but the initial value of state is `0` (not `'0'`). For this reason both tests always return false.

In addition, avoid setting conditions when not necessary. `else` already mean "all the other options", so if you have one variable that can be only A or B, don't write `if A ... else if B ...`; the second condition is necessary (and meaningful) only if the condition is actually something you care of (so you want to exclude condition C).

I started modifying your sketch from the new version, and here are the things I modified:

- Variables were set to type `uint8_t`; `int` is not efficient on 8-bit platforms, so use 8-bit variables whenever you can
- Instead of using multiple triggers, I used a single variable (`ledState`) to calculate the state in each loop. This way it is much easier to track the modifications
- simplified the input management: now it turns on the led when the input is high, and does nothing (leaves it off) when it is low
- simplified the bluetooth management. With a `'1'` it turns on the led, and all the other chars set it off; if you need only a '0' to turn it off you can easily modify the parentheses to ignore other chars

This is the code I wrote. NOTE: I did not test it, so there may be residual bugs. Let me know if it works as you expect or want some additional clarifications:

```
uint8_t ledPin = 2;
uint8_t interruptor = 3;
uint8_t bluetoothState = '0';

void setup() {
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(interruptor, INPUT);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    uint8_t ledState = LOW;
    
    if (digitalRead(interruptor)) {
        ledState = HIGH;
        Serial1.println("LED: on (switch)");
    }
    
    if(Serial1.available() > 0){
        bluetoothState = Serial1.read();
    }
    
    if (bluetoothState == '1') {
        ledState = HIGH;
        Serial1.println("LED: on (BT)");
    }
    
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    if (ledState == LOW) {
        Serial1.println("LED: off");
    }
}
```

Things still to do (IMHO):

- make a robust button handler (for instance using the debounce library)
- get rid of the serial debug outputs
- make a better serial protocol

Comment: Hopefully the problem was resolved in the intervening 2.5 yrs ;)

Comment: O_O why was it in the homepage then? I assumed it was something like 10 minutes old LOL.. sorry for the necroposting

Comment: :shrug: It's a low-traffic site so stuff gets bumped for visibility ;) And it's fine anyway--it'll help somebody, if not the OP :)

Comment: 3.5 years now. :)

Comment: *I assumed it was something like 10 minutes old* ... yes, SE does do odd things like making posts look relevant when they are not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to invalidate the `state` variable when `Serial` is not available, otherwise you will produce strange behaviours.

```cpp
if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
    state = Serial1.read();
} else {
    state = -1; // not valid
}
```

Also, serial values will be characters, not integers, so compare with character values, e.g.,

```cpp
if (state == '1')
```